# Select nested div within LI element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select the div contained within the `LI` element using jQuery when the `LI` is clicked, here's the code I have so far.

```
jQuery( ".about-nav-item" ).click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next('.white-content').show();
});
```

HTML

```
<nav id="about-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="about-nav-item">
            <a href="#">Story</a>

            <div class="white-content">TEST</div>

        </li>
        <li class="about-nav-item">
            <a href="#">Approach</a>

            <div class="white-content">TEST1</div>

        </li>
        <li class="about-nav-item">
            <a href="#">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class="about-nav-item">
            <a href="#">Network</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
.white-content {
    width: 220%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 95%;
    top: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    min-height: 350px;
    color: black;
    display: none;
}
```

The problem is that on clicking the element, it simply does nothing and doesn't show the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.children()` or `.find()` here since `.about-nav-item` is the parent of `.white-content` div:

```
jQuery( ".about-nav-item" ).click(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.white-content').show(); // or jQuery(this).children('.white-content').show();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmepF/)**

Comment: spot on @Felix.  fyi @James, `.next()` moves laterally in the dom tree, equivalent to the native javascript `.nextSibling` property.  `.find()` will traverse each node of the dom tree using, in this example, `jQuery(this)` as the root. `.children(...selector...)` will filter an element's direct children to those matching "selector." In the case of find and children, you should expect that in some cases, the result will contain a set of elements (e.g., there may be more than one)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find()` to do this:

```
jQuery(".about-nav-item").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.white-content').show();
});
```

Or a contextual selector:

```
jQuery(".about-nav-item").click(function() {
    jQuery('.white-content', this).show();
});
```